# Is there a way in tkinter to italicize a single word in a text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, typography

I am trying to make a text widget display some non-italicized characters in the same line as italicized ones.  For example, I want it to say "This is *my* text widget" all in the same line.

As far as I know, you can only change the font formatting of the entire widget, not individual words.  I've looked online quite a bit, but could not answer this question.  I am wondering if this is possible, or if I should try a different method from using text widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a tag to a range of characters in a text widget. Each tag can be configured with a variety of styles and a custom font. Some styles can be applied directly to the tag, some need to be applied to a font that is associated with the tag. Italics is one such style that must be applied to a font.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tk.Tk()

normal_font = Font(family="helvetica", size=20)
italic_font = Font(family="helvetica", size=20, slant="italic")

text = tk.Text(root, wrap="none", width=40, height=10, font=normal_font)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text.tag_configure("italics", font=italic_font)

text.insert("end", "This is ", "", "my", "italics", " text widget")

root.mainloop()
```

Note: the `insert` method typically is used to insert one string at a time, but it actually takes a variable number of arguments in the form of *text*, *tag*, *text*, *tag*, ... (the final tag can be omitted).

In the above example, we insert the whole string using a single call to `insert`, but notice how we apply a null tag to some parts, and the tag "italics" to the word "my". That one call to `insert` does exactly the same thing as these three lines, but in a more concise format:

```
text.insert("end", "This is ")
text.insert("end", "my", "italics")
text.insert("end", " text widget")
```

Another way to do this is to insert the whole string at once, and then add the tag in a separate statement:

```
text.insert("end", "This is my text widget")
text.tag_add("italics", "1.8", "1.9")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for!  I also appreciate the description of each part, that made your answer very easy to understand.  Thank you very much for your help, and I hope you have a nice day.

Comment: @StillNobody I only add that you can use tuple with many tags `text.insert("end", "my", ("italics", "red_background") )`. And you can assign new value to existing tag (using again `tag_configure()`) and it will automatically change it in `Text`

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, tkinter's text widgets doesn't have direct access to font styles. A workaround could be to split the line of text into separate text widget entries, applying different styles to each entry. That could create something similar to the desired effect.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x100")

text_widget = tk.Text(root, wrap="none", height=1)
text_widget.pack()

text_widget.insert(tk.END, "This is ")
text_widget.tag_add("italic", "1.0", "1.4")
text_widget.tag_config("italic", font=("Times", 12, "italic"))

text_widget_italic = tk.Text(root, wrap="none", height=1)
text_widget_italic.pack()

text_widget_italic.insert(tk.END, "my")
text_widget_italic.tag_add("italic", "1.0", "1.2")
text_widget_italic.tag_config("italic", font=("Times", 12, "italic"))

text_widget.insert(tk.END, " text widget")
text_widget.tag_add("normal", "1.5", "1.end")
text_widget.tag_config("normal", font=("Times", 12))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no need to create multiple text widgets.

Comment: it could be simpler to use `tag` directly in `insert` - `insert(tk.END, "This is ", 'italic')`

Comment: Thanks for your help; I'll try fidgeting around with adapting your code to get something that fits my needs.